# ERROR A2070 : "invalid instruction operands" for MOVSD (SSE2)

Tags: assembly, x86, sse, masm

I am learning assembly to enhance my C++ efficiency and am trying to write a vector library using SIMD instructions, however I need to be able to access individual elements from time to time and was wondering if there was an easier way to do it than using VextractF128 and Movlpd/Movhpd :

```
.Data
vecta STRUCT 16
    x REAL8 ?
    y REAL8 ?
    z REAL8 ?
    w REAL8 ?
vecta ENDS

vectb UNION     ;If I understand correctly this will force anything in a to be in b as well
    a YMMWORD ? ;since they share the same space
    b vecta {?,?,?,?}
vectb ENDS

.CODE
Somefunc PROC   ;uses _vectorcall convention and has one parameter to be passed in YMM0
    VMOVAPD [vectb.a], YMM0
    MOVSD   XMM2, [vectb.b.x]  ;this gives the error
    ; make other changes to vectb
    VMOVAPD YMM0, [vectb.a]
    RET
Somefunc ENDP
```

I've also set the /arch:SSE2 compiler option but that doesn't seem to help.
Other things I've tried :

```
Somefunc PROC
    VMOVAPD [vecta.x],YMM0 ; compiler seems to think this is ok
    MOVSD   XMM2, [vecta.x]; as this line is still the only error
    ...
Somefunc ENDP
```

And :

```
Somefunc PROC
    VMOVAPD [vectb.a], YMM0
    MOVSD   XMM2, [vectb.b] ;Now gives a different error :[A2009]"syntax error in expression"
    ...
Somefunc ENDP
```

Comment: I believe when you are moving [vectb.b.x] you are passing wrong length value. You may move [vectb.b] (a mword)and not its subset x (a word or dword).

Comment: @DavidBS Thank you but it still give an error : "syntax error in expression"[A2009] .I've updated my question to show this.

Comment: None of the vector instructions you've posted should assemble correctly as they're all using immediate operands. The symbol vectb` is a type, it doesn't refer to a location in memory. So both `vectb.a` and `vectb.b.x` evaluate to 0, the offsets of the members. Post your actual code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @RossRidge That is the actual code , as I've mentioned earlier I'm learning.

Comment: No, the assembler would be giving many more errors than you described if that was your actual code. In addition to giving an error for all of the vector instructions, even the one you said the "compiler seems to think this is ok", you'd get errors because your code is missing a `.model` directive and an `END` directive. You haven't posted code that reproduces the problem as you described it.

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to write a vector library using SIMD instructions... to enhance my C++ efficiency

Here's a code-review based on that.  I hope this helps you improve the efficiency and quality of your code.

---

Mixing VEX-encoded instructions and non-VEX instructions is a critical performance bug, as Intel explains in [a nice article with diagrams](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-avx-state-transitions-migrating-sse-code-to-avx).  Use `vmovsd` and `v` versions of any other 128b operations you want to do, unless you ran `vzeroupper` since the last time you used a 256b instruction.

For more info on writing efficient x86 asm, see [Agner Fog's Optimizing Assembly](http://agner.org/optimize/) guide.  There is so much good stuff in there:

- How to decide which instructions to use based on the performance characteristics of specific microarchitectures
- How to rearrange data in vectors.  There's a whole set of tables of stuff like: "instructions that combine data from two vectors", or "instructions that can broadcast within a vector".
- How to think about asm optimization, in terms of dependency chains, latency, and throughput.
- How to deal with the ABI difference between Windows and everything else.
- instruction tables and detailed microarch info.

See also the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for more links.

---

> I need to be able to access individual elements from time to time and was wondering if there was an easier way to do it than using VextractF128 and Movlpd/Movhpd

Yes, but it's slower.  For maximum performance, you (or your C++ compiler) generally needs to use shuffle instructions, not store/reload to memory.  movlpd / movhpd only work as stores/loads, not between registers.  But you can use `movhlps` for the identical purpose of merging 64 bits from the high element of one register into the low element of another.

Spilling to memory, then reloading and modifying that memory has significant latency (like 5 cycles for each memory round trip).  Then a wide vector load from memory that you just wrote with multiple narrow stores will suffer a store-forwarding failure, causing another ~10 cycles of latency.

So even if `Somefunc` did nothing more than store, reload scalar, store again scalar, reload vector, it would introduce about 20 cycles of latency IIRC to the dependency chain involving its input/output, on Intel Haswell.

---

Don't store/reload to get the low element (`.x`): it's already the low element of the whole vector where you can use it directly with `vmulsd` or whatever.

e.g. you should have used

```
Somefunc PROC   ;uses _vectorcall convention and has one parameter to be passed in YMM0


    ;; VMOVAPD    [vectb.a], YMM0    ; don't do this, it was a bad plan

    ; MOVSD   XMM2, [vectb.b.x]  ;this gives the error
    ;; should be:
    vmovapd    xmm2, xmm0    ; the low element of xmm2 now contains the low element of xmm0.   The high128 of ymm2 is zeroed (instead of preserved like movapd would).
    ; or better: don't even copy it at all.  You can use `xmm0` as a source operand for `v...sd` scalar instructions just fine.


    ;;; Or, if you needed the high double zeroed, use
    vxorps     xmm3, xmm3, xmm3        ; zero ymm3 (not a typo: upper 128 zeroed implicitly).
    vmovsd     xmm2, xmm3, xmm0        ; merge low double of xmm0 into the all-zeros, putting the result in xmm2 while keeping our all-zeros around for future use.

    ;; get  .y:
    vmovhlps   xmm1, xmm3, xmm0        ; merge the high 64b of xmm0 with all-zeros, putting the result in xmm1

    vextractf128  xmm4, ymm0, 1        ; .z in the low element of xmm4, garbage in the high element)

    vmovhlps   xmm5, xmm3, xmm4        ; .w in the low element, zero in the high element


    ; make other changes to vectb


    ;; re-combine with unpcklpd to combine two scalars into the same vector
    ;; and vinsertf128

    ;; Storing and re-loading is not a good plan for re-combining either.
    ;; VMOVAPD    YMM0, [vectb.a]     ; store-forwarding failure here
    RET
```

---

#### Your struct / union declarations:

You probably don't need a union.  This is assembly language, just make the operand-size explicit to tell MASM you don't want it to complain about operand-size mismatches based on how you defined your labels.

e.g. `vmovapd ymmword ptr [whatever you want], ymm0`

---

**More importantly, using a static buffer like that will make your function not thread-safe.  If you need scratch space, you should reserve space on the stack for it.**  Make it 32B-aligned like this:

```
;; Usually compilers will actually align the stack pointer to 32B
;; but if you can spare another integer register, I think you save insns doing this.
lea    rdx, [rsp-32]
sub    rsp, 48           ; assumes RSP was 16B-aligned
and    rdx, -32          ; Same as ~0x0f
```

RDX now points to a 32B-aligned block of stack space, which is at either [rsp] or [rsp+16], if RSP was 16B-aligned beforehand.  If you don't know that, AND could bring RDX down below RSP, which wouldn't be safe if you don't have a red-zone.  (Windows doesn't, everything else does).  In that case, `sub rsp, 64`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to create a variable of vectb :

```
.Data
...
...
vectc vectb {?}

.CODE
Somefunc PROC
    VMOVAPD   [vectc.a]  ,   YMM0
    MOVSD     XMM2       ,   [vectc.b.x]
    ...
Somefunc ENDP
```